# Not able to read value from EDIT box (windows programming and C)

Tags: c, windows

I need help with this code. I need to set the focus to a edit button and read the value entered in the edit box and move it to a variable for further processing. This code creates a text prompt with TextOut() which says " Enter the value of mass:" and an editbox with an IDC_EDIT_MASS and hEditMASS next to it.

I am not able to read the value from edit box into variable mass.
And the code is as follows *

```
#define IDC_EDIT_MASS 103         // Edit box identifier
RESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM
 lParam)
{ 
   HWND hEditMASS;
   HDC hDC;
   PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
   HFONT        font;
   float mass;
   char msgMASS[]="Enter the value of mass:";
   switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
      {
      case WM_CREATE :
          hEditMASS=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, “EDIT",
            "",    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            550,
            200,
            200,
            20,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_EDIT_MASS,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
            Break;
      case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) { 
          case IDC_EDIT_MASS:
            SendMessage(hEditMASS,WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), 
                reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
            int ctxtlen=GetWindowTextlength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT_MASS));
            GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT_MASS), buffer,(cTxtLen + 1);
            mass=atoi(buffer);
            MessageBox(NULL,buffer,"Information",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
          }
         Break;
       case WM_SETFOCUS :
         SetFocus (hwnd) ;
         break;
       case WM_PAINT:
         hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
         //inputs prompts ...
         TextOut(hDC,300,200,msgMASS,sizeof(msgMASS));
         EndPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
         break;
       case WM_DESTROY:
         PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
         break;
       default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
          return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
       return 0;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

`hEditMASS` is an local, automatic-storage-duration variable. You set it when the message is `WM_CREATE`. However, you then access it when the message is `WM_COMMAND`. Automatic-storage-duration variables do not retain their value between calls. In order for it to retain its value, you must either make it global or make it static, e.g.:

```
static HWND hEditMASS;
```

Keep in mind that you'll probably only be able to use your window procedure for one window now, since creating any other window with the same window procedure will end up using the same `hEditMASS` variable, and when you next try to access `hEditMASS`, it will point to the edit control in the most-recently-created window with that window procedure.

Comment: I shall try it. Thanks.

Comment: problem with case WM_COMMAND stmts, particularly with GetWindowtextlength() and GetWindowText(). And more over is  the "case WM_SETFOCUS" help in setting focus to the edit box when program runs?. Because nothing such thing happens so I  need to use mouse to select the edit box and try to enter the value though Im not able to do so, as Messagebox() in that WM_COMMAND gets executed.